# Jackson, serialize one attribute of a reference

Tags: java, json, spring, serialization, jackson

When serializing a Java object which has other object references, I need to serialize only one attribute of the nested object(usual case of foreign key, so serialize the "id" attribute of the object reference). Ingore everything else.

For example, I have two classes which I need to serialize to JSON & XML(removed JPA annotations for clarity):

**Relationship: User ->(one-to-many) AddressInformation;
Also: AddressInformation ->(one-to-one) User**

```
@XmlRootElement
public class User {
    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private AddressInformation defaultAddress;
    private Set<AddressInformation> addressInformation;

    public User() {
    }

    @JsonProperty(value = "id")
    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @JsonProperty(value = "firstname")
    @XmlAttribute(name = "firstname")
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @JsonProperty(value = "lastname")
    @XmlAttribute(name = "lastname")
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @JsonProperty(value = "email")
    @XmlAttribute(name = "email")
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public Set<AddressInformation> getAddressInformation() {
        return addressInformation;
    }

    public void setAddressInformation(Set<AddressInformation> addressInformation) {
        this.addressInformation = addressInformation;
    }

    @JsonProperty(value = "defaultaddress")
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
    public AddressInformation getDefaultAddress() {
        return defaultAddress;
    }

    public void setDefaultAddress(AddressInformation defaultAddress) {
        this.defaultAddress = defaultAddress;
    }
}
```

AddressInformation:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class AddressInformation  {
    private String id;
    private String address;
    private String details;
    private User user;

    @JsonProperty(value = "id")
    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @JsonProperty(value = "details")
    @XmlAttribute(name = "details")
    public String getDetails() {
        return details;
    }

    public void setDetails(String details) {
        this.details = details;
    }

    @JsonProperty(value = "address")
    @XmlAttribute(name = "address")
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public AddressInformation() {
        super();
    }
}
enter code here
```

When serializing User for example, I need:

```
{
  "id" : "idofuser01",
  "email" : "some.email@gmail.com",
  "status" : "OK",
  "firstname" : "Filan",
  "lastname" : "Ovni",
  "defaultaddressid" : "idofaddress01",
}
enter code here
```

When serializing AddressInformation:

```
{
  "id" : "idofaddress01",
  "address" : "R.8. adn",
  "details" : "blah blah",
  "userid" : "idofuser01",
}
```

I have tried `@JsonManageReference` & `@JsonBackReference` with no success. As you can see I also tried  `@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just Found a way using Jackson 2.1+ .

Annotate object references with(this will pick only the `id` attribute of `AddressInformation`):

```
@JsonProperty(value = "defaultaddressid")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
@JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true) 
public AddressInformation getDefaultAddress() {
    return defaultAddress;
}
```

Serialization works very well.

Comment: This works, but I dont understand what its doing. Can you elaborate ?

Comment: Yes, can anyone elaborate why the above is working ? Thanks.

Comment: I usually put `@JsonIdentityInfo` at class level and `@JsonIdentityReference` at attribut level (the one referencing other class). `@JsonIdentityInfo` avoids infinite recursion when serializing (like User1->Address1->User1->Address1 ->...) writing the "id" field of the referenced entity instead trying to serialize the complete POJO. BUT the main behavior is to serialize the first occurrence POJO completely, and further references only writes the 'id'. `@JsonIdentityReference` reconfigures the behavior to always write the referenced id, not serialize the complete POJO; so: Address1->"John".

Answer (score 3):

You can implement custom deserializer for this class and use it in `User` class. Example implementation:

```
class AddressInformationIdJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<AddressInformation> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(AddressInformation value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeString(value.getId());
    }
}
```

And configuration in `User` class:

```
@JsonProperty(value = "defaultaddress")
@JsonSerialize(using = AddressInformationIdJsonSerializer.class)
public AddressInformation getDefaultAddress() {
    return defaultAddress;
}
```

**### Generic solution for all classes which implement one interface ###**
You can create interface which contains `String getId()` method:

```
interface Identifiable {
    String getId();
}
```

Serializer for this interface could look like that:

```
class IdentifiableJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Identifiable> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Identifiable value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeString(value.getId());
    }
}
```

And now, you can use this serializer for all `Identifiable` implementations. For example:

```
@JsonProperty(value = "defaultaddress")
@JsonSerialize(using = IdentifiableJsonSerializer.class)
public AddressInformation getDefaultAddress() {
    return defaultAddress;
}
```

of course: `AddressInformation` have to implement this interface:

```
class AddressInformation implements Identifiable {
    ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to write such generic serializer (without using reflection) to use wherever I need the functionality?

Comment: You want to use this serializer for all POJO classes which have "private String id" property, yes? Could you confirm?

Comment: I solved the problem but yes, It would be interesting to have a generic serializer for all POJOs.

Comment: Yes, I saw your solution - nice one. Please, see my answer after edition. Maybe you will use it in future for similar problem.