# JPA persistence: store id or store entity

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I am building a Java EE Restful service which I use for operations in an SQL database.
In my SQL database I have a table PRODUCT containing all information of a product including the owner. The owner is stored as a foreign key to another table USER.
The question I'm asking is whether I should store the owner id or the owner object in the Java class corresponding with the PRODUCT table.

So should I use

```
class Product {
    String name;
    Integer owner_id;
}
```

or

```
class Product {
    String name;
    User owner;
}
```

?

(I removed all the annotations etc. to keep the question clear)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To take the advantage of ORM(such as Hibernate), you store the reference. Then, when querying `Product`, Hibernate populates the `User`

If you don't store the reference but simply the foreign key, and if you need `User` information from `Product`, you will have to do additional query to load `User`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! An additional problem I have when I store the reference and not the key, is that, when I GET a PRODUCT object, the JSON representation of the owner is embedded in the JSON representation of the PRODUCT, while I only want the id of the owner. Is there a clean way to solve this?

Comment: Yes, if you're using Jackson to do the conversion in JSON, you can embed only the id of the owner. I've answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19118059/jackson-serialize-one-field-of-dependency

Comment: I tried the suggestion you gave in that thread, however, it seems like my jackson annotations are ignored. I added jackson core, databind and annotations libraries to the build path. This doesn't seem to work and I can't find documentation about how to get them to work. Until now I only used jaxb annotations. Can you give me some advice?

Answer (score 1):

You can use either id or User object depending on how you gonna work with the Product instances.
Standard model way is to store object and than you will be able to get the Owner from the product:

`productInst.getOwner()`;

By storing the id you are limmitig  yourself to getting only id:

```
Integet ownerId = productInst.getOwnerId();
// and you will need more code to get the user instance:
userDao.getById(ownerId);
```

In simple cases when I am sure that I need only id I simplify the object by putting only id. But in most cases it's smarter to map object to be able to retrieve related entities.