# How to use JsonProperty annotation over a class reference

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I have following class

```
public class Employee {

@JsonPropery("name")
private String name;

@JsonPropery("address")
private Address address;

// getter setters
}
```

And

```
public class Address {

@JsonPropery("street")
private String name;

@JsonPropery("location")
private String name;

// getter setters

}
```

Now while generating the JSON for this model, following error is obtained:

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation 
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:251)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:183)
```

Can you Please help out in what should be used in place of `@JsonProperty` here.

If the referenced class is removed , Proper JSON is obtained. Is there any specific annotation to be used for class reference ?

Comment: I guess the problem is in your call to the rest, in the request headers set Accept header to **application/json**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring MVC - HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197268/spring-mvc-httpmediatypenotacceptableexception)

Comment: @Luciano van der Veekens 1 this is a different issue. I have already checked the earler one and configuration is correct

Comment: @BobZant that is also there

Comment: Posting the JSON you tried will be much helpful to identify the problem.

Comment: @ chsdk I do not get a JSON in place server throws an error.

Comment: @chsdk On removing class reference I could obtain a JSON so any specific handling required for class reference ?

Comment: @SanyamGoel Ok, I got it. Don't you have an `Id` in your adress class?

Comment: @chsdk no I do not have

Comment: @SanyamGoel I thought you can try using [**JsonIdentityInfo** annotation](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIdentityInfo.html) with your `Adress` field, for further details you can check **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19118059/jackson-serialize-one-attribute-of-a-reference**.